# How to work with the set of lines within the txt file?

Tags: python, readlines

I am new to Python and currently working on my project in college.
So I have the file "inst.txt" and I need to parse it. The file that I have is below. GG represents the start of the loop.

```
     LI; R4,; 260
     LI; R5,; 272
     LI; R1,; 8
     LI; R2,; 4
     LI; R3,; 0

GG:  L.D; F1,; 4(R4)

     L.D; F2,; 8(R5)
     ADD.D; F4,; F6,; F2
     SUB.D; F5,; F7,; F1
     MUL.D; F6,; F1,; F5
     ADD.D; F7,; F2,; F6
     ADD.D; F6,; F1,; F7
     DADDI; R4,; R4,; 20
     DADDI; R5,; R5,; 8
     DSUB; R1,; R1,, R2
     BNE; R1,; R3,; GG
     HLT;
     HLT;
```

I need the data to come out in the same way they are in this file using ";" as delimeter and array of [0:2] and [0:3] respectively. How can I do that?

The code that I am using right now is as follows:

```
#Accessing a text file
import os

file = open ("inst.txt","r")
for lines[0:4] in file:
   fields = lines.split(";")

Instruction = fields[0]
Destreg = fields[1]
Data = fields[2]
print(Instruction + Destreg + Data)

file.close()
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\parsing_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    fields = lines.split(";")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

or if I use this code:

```
import os

file = open("inst.txt","r")
for line in file:
  fields = line.split(";")
  Instruction = fields[0]
  Destreg = fields[1]
  Data = fields[2]
  print(Instruction + Destreg + Data)

file.close()
```

but the result comes only in such way as

```
 LI R4, 260

     LI R5, 272

     LI R1, 8

     LI R2, 4

     LI R3, 0

GG:  L.D F1, 4(R4)

     L.D F2, 8(R5)

     ADD.D F4, F6,
     SUB.D F5, F7,
     MUL.D F6, F1,
     ADD.D F7, F2,
     ADD.D F6, F1,
     DADDI R4, R4,
     DADDI R5, R5,
     DSUB R1, R1,, R2

     BNE R1, R3,
```

So I am missing the third value of registers.

Comment: When I run your code it gives me `NameError: name 'lines' is not defined` for the line `for lines[0:4] in file:`, so I can't reproduce what you say happens (an `AttributeError`).

Comment: I'm confused about the task. Are you trying to read data from the file into lists and then use the lists to print the data out exactly as it looks in the input file?

Comment: `for lines[0:4] in file:` should be giving you an error before you even get to the `split` line

Answer (score 0):

See the following part of your input as an example for understanding the problem:

```
ADD.D; F4,; F6,; F2
```

The mapping to your variables will be :

```
Instruction = fields[0]     # "ADD.D"
Destreg = fields[1]         # "F4"
Data = fields[2]            # "F6"
```

You are simply missing an additional variable assignment for `"F2"`

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're asking, perhaps indirectly, how the same code can deal with the two different cases in which a line contains 3 substrings or 4 substrings.

One approach is not to assign each `fields[i]` to a uniquely-named variable at all
 (`Instruction`, `Destreg`, etc). Instead just use the `fields` variable itself, so that later (whenever the program logic requires it) you can test whether `len(fields)` is 3 or 4 and react accordingly.

Another approach is to assign a further variable conditionally:

```
Instruction = fields[0]
Destreg = fields[1]
Data = fields[2]
RedShirt = fields[3] if len(fields) > 3 else None
```

Sooner or later I expect your program logic will require you to test whether `RedShirt is None` so there's little difference in the amount of programming.

Another helpful step will be to strip whitespace from each field. You can do that at the beginning:

```
fields = [x.strip() for x in line.split(";")]    # instead of just fields = line.split(";")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for advice. If I use that line of code  RedShirt = fields[3] if len(fields) > 3 else None I am getting error TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly. What can I do in that case , or may be there is another operation I can use instead of None?

Comment: @DanF You're getting that error, of course, from code you're not showing us. Possibly just from appending it to a string with `+` for printing—but in your next step there will be all kinds of additional code for processing the fields (which you shouldn't show us, because it's not relevant to the question).  My point is that in *either* case the code-we-don't-see will, one way or another, need to be specifically written to be sensitive to whether there is an empty field. Given that proviso, you can use *anything you want* as the placeholder for "no data available". Maybe the empty string `''` ?